# Search for sequence in Uint8List

Tags: dart

Is there a fast (native) method to search for a sequence in a `Uint8List`?

```
///
/// Return index of first occurrence of seq in list
///
int indexOfSeq(Uint8List list, Uint8List seq) {
  ...
}
```

EDIT: Changed `List<int>` into `Uint8List`

Comment: Not build into Dart but it is easy enough to make you own method which are "fast". What do you want to return if the sequence is not part of list?

Comment: Does it help if we know that the underlying lists are Uint8Lists?

Comment: Does not make much of a difference. But it is still easy enough to add an extension method which provide such functionality.

Comment: I know the easy approach, but I was hoping that someone points me to a nice package with a native implementation, e.g. using memmem via FFI.

Comment: Not really sure why that would be more efficient? You can do the search with a worst case of reading the whole list once.

Comment: Sure, but the constant factor of a function written purely native in C should probably be faster than one written in Dart...

Comment: The Dart code are compiled at runtime to native code so it should be able to perform rather well. If you do see a performance penalty, you are welcome to create a benchmark and report the issue to the Dart SDK issue tracker: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no *built-in* way to search for a sequence of elements in a list.
I am also not aware of any `dart:ffi` based implementations.

The simplest approach would be:

```dart
extension IndexOfElements<T> on List<T> {
  int indexOfElements(List<T> elements, [int start = 0]) {
    if (elements.isEmpty) return start;
    var end = length - elements.length;
    if (start > end) return -1;
    var first = elements.first;
    var pos = start;
    while (true) {
      pos = indexOf(first, pos);
      if (pos < 0 || pos > end) return -1;
      for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (this[pos + i] != elements[i]) {
          pos++;
          continue;
        }
      }
      return pos;
    }
  }
}
```

This has worst-case time complexity O(`length`*`elements.length`). There are several more algorithms with better worst-case complexity, but they also have larger constant factors and more expensive pre-computations ([KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), [BMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm)). Unless you search for the same long list several times, or do so in a very, very long list, they're unlikely to be faster in practice (and they'd probably have an API where you compile the pattern first, then search with it.)

Comment: I was thinking that probably accessing memmem via ffi would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dart:ffi` to bind to `memmem` from `string.h` as you suggested.

We do the same with binding to `malloc` from `stdlib.h` in `package:ffi` ([source](https://github.com/dart-lang/ffi/blob/a5d4232cd38562c75a3ed847baa340e399538028/lib/src/allocation.dart#L8-L16)).

```dart
final DynamicLibrary stdlib = Platform.isWindows
    ? DynamicLibrary.open('kernel32.dll')
    : DynamicLibrary.process();

final PosixMalloc posixMalloc =
    stdlib.lookupFunction<Pointer Function(IntPtr), Pointer Function(int)>('malloc');
```

Edit: as lrn pointed out, we cannot expose the inner data pointer of a Uint8List at the moment, because the GC might relocate it.

One could use dart_api.h and use the FFI to pass `TypedData` through the FFI trampoline as `Dart_Handle` and use `Dart_TypedDataAcquireData` from the `dart_api.h` to access the inner data pointer.

(If you want to use this in Flutter, we would need to expose `Dart_TypedDataAcquireData` and `Dart_TypedDataReleaseData` in `dart_api_dl.h` https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40607 I've filed https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44442 to track this.)

Alternatively, could address https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36707 so that we could just expose the inner data pointer of a Uint8List directly in the FFI trampoline.

Comment: Is memmem available on all platforms? I could allocate native memory and operate on that, but would be nice if we had a List<int> by a Pointer that holds a chunk of native memory...

Comment: Btw Daco, beside using Flutter at work with heavy usage of FFI (HERE WeGo), this problem here is for my home automation system. I switched my custom solution from a 6 years old HTML5/JS-frontend with a Phyton middleware to a Flutter-frontend (running on a bunch of tablets in my house) with a Dart middleware (transcodes my cams and bridges to FHEM). I need to say that standing up the Dart middleware on a Rasperry Pi worked like a charm!!!